# Find the linear transformation that maps from $R^3$ to $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

[image]

So I have answered a and gotten $ \sqrt 2/ 36 [1, 4, -1]^T$ I am struggling with b). And here is the answer sheet

[image]

What I don't understand is the difference between for example $T(v_1) = v_3$ and $[T(v_1)]_B = [v_3]_B$ and also how they got the answer $(0, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the basis $B$, $[v_3]_B=\begin {pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end {pmatrix}$, since it's the third element.  That's $v_3=0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+1\cdot v_3.$

Since $T(v_1)=v_3$, it follows that their expressions in the basis are equal: $$[T(v_1)]_B=[v_3]_B$$.

So, that's the first column of the matrix.

Comment: Basis B is not given so how come $v_3 = 0 * v_1 + 0*v_2 + 1 * v_3$?

Comment: The basis $B$ is $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3\}$.

Comment: Why did we multiply it by (0,0,1) then? I am confused is the basis B equal to the standard basis?

Comment: No, the phenomenon,  which is pretty important,  is that the $i$th vector of a basis,  *in terms of that same basis*, is $e_i$.

Comment: Also if you look at my answer to the question a) I got the vector $v_3 = x$ where x is a orthonormal vector? All I am saying is why did $v_3  = (0,0,1) in your answer?

Comment: I probably should have written $[v_3]_B$.  I meant expressed in the basis $B$.

Comment: I am still confused what basis B is? Is it the standard basis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141730/discussion-between-egg-nog-and-kib-me).